# what does Camden.RELEASE in version of spring cloud denote?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies, spring-cloud

I have seen this piece of code in a gradle file where we specify the imports. Can anyone kindly clarify what is Camden Release in spring?

I had been trying to maintain the same version of spring across the project.

## build.gradle file

```
dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.RELEASE"
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got confused with the names, Spring cloud name their release versions.

Spring Cloud is an umbrella project consisting of independent projects with, in principle, different release cadences. To manage the portfolio a BOM (Bill of Materials) is published with a curated set of dependencies on the individual project (see below). The release trains have names, not versions, to avoid confusion with the sub-projects. The names are an alphabetic sequence (so you can sort them chronologically) with names of London Tube stations ("Angel" is the first release, "Brixton" is the second). When point releases of the individual projects accumulate to a critical mass, or if there is a critical bug in one of them that needs to be available to everyone, the release train will push out "service releases" with names ending ".SRX", where "X" is a number.

Table 1. Release train Spring Boot compatibility
Release Train   Boot Version
Greenwich

2.1.x

Finchley

2.0.x

Edgware

1.5.x

Dalston

1.5.x

For more details  check release trains section in https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: I wouldn't say tube stations, but London areas in general. There isn't a "Camden" or a"Greenwich" tube station, for instance.